# Why do I get undefined on my array from ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am pulling in some data from database using Ajax. The data is stores as a integer within the database.

I am adding each row to an array to make up a binary string of what is coming in for later comparison.

The code is shown below. The issue I have is the result has an undefined at the front of each array.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "######.php",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        len = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['motorhome']
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['caravan'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['tent'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['elect'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['toilet'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['shower'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['dog'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['fishing'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['beach'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['swimming'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['pub'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['adult'];
        }
        console.log("incoming Binary = ", markerCatBinary);
    }
});
```

Console log result

```
incoming Binary =  
Array(4)
0: "undefined111110100010"
1: "undefined100000110010"
2: "undefined100000110010"
3: "undefined100000101000"
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I have tried parseInt but this gives Nan on all arrays

below example of first row data return from database

```
adult: "0"
beach: "0"
caravan: "1"
dog: "1"
elect: "1"
fishing: "0"
id: "27"
latitude: "0.43082571029663086"
longitude: "51.20949935913086"
motorhome: "1"
pub: "1"
shower: "0"
site_name: "The WoolPack Inn"
swimming: "0"
tent: "1"
toilet: "1"
```

Edit

Below is the full script with variables/arrays and the map function

```
let marker = [];
let markerCatBinary = [];
let infoWindow = [];
let lonMarker = [];
let latMarker = [];
let icon = [];
let siteName = [];
let map;
let contents = [];
let id = [];
let motorhome = [];
let caravan = [];
let tent = [];
let elect = [];
let toilet = [];
let shower = [];
let dog = [];
let fishing = [];
let beach = [];
let swimming = [];
let pub = [];
let adult = [];
let len;

function initMap() {

    const center = { lat: 52, lng: 0.5 };
    // The map, centered at kent
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: center,
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "getMapData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            len = Object.keys(data).length;
            for (i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) {
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['motorhome']
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['caravan'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['tent'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['elect'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['toilet'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['shower'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['dog'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['fishing'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['beach'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['swimming'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['pub'];
            markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['adult'];
        }
        console.log("incoming Binary = ", markerCatBinary);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where do you define the variable: `markerCatBinary`? Can you add that code to the question?

Comment: I have edited and added the full code including the variable/array declaration and the function for the map

Comment: Accessing a non-existing property/array element returns `undefined`. `markerCatBinary[i]` doesn't exist when the loop is entered. The first assignment should be `markerCatBinary[i] = data[i]['motorhome']` (`=` not `+=`) instead.

Comment: Flexi you are correct thank you please add this as an answer and I will mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `for` loop, add an empty string to the array index. That can solve the issue.

The reason might be due to that you didn't initialize the string.

```js
var data = [{
  adult: "0",
  beach: "0",
  caravan: "1",
  dog: "1",
  elect: "1",
  fishing: "0",
  id: "27",
  latitude: "0.43082571029663086",
  longitude: "51.20949935913086",
  motorhome: "1",
  pub: "1",
  shower: "0",
  site_name: "The WoolPack Inn",
  swimming: "0",
  tent: "1",
  toilet: "1",
}]

var markerCatBinary = [];

for (i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
  markerCatBinary[i] = "";
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['motorhome']
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['caravan'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['tent'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['elect'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['toilet'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['shower'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['dog'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['fishing'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['beach'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['swimming'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['pub'];
  markerCatBinary[i] += data[i]['adult'];
}

console.log(markerCatBinary)
```